# jQuery JSTree - check_move and prepare_move fired mutiple times

Tags: jquery, jstree

I need to check if the current node can be moved. I'm able to do this, but "check_move" callback or binded "prepare_move" function is called multiple times. It's annoying when the same message in alert box is diplayed few times.

How I can display the alert box one time or how i can modify JSTree in order to callback wont be displayed one after another?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's called every time you drag the node you are moving over a new node, to check if it's a valid move. So if you grab a node and move it over 4 nodes, `check_move` will get called at least 4 times.

If you are debugging try `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, it will work better for you (look for the messages in the JavaScript console).

If you want to display an alert or something *after* the move is complete, bind to the `move_node` event instead.